# postgresql: relation does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm new using pl pgsql, with my pseudo code below i'm getting this error:

> relation "Client.seniority_day" does not exist

How to resolve it please?

**code**

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS table_sen_seniority;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Client.table_sen_seniority(granularity text, OUT max_date date)
RETURNS record
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    table_sen text := 'Client.seniority'||granularity;

 BEGIN
     execute format('SELECT MIN(dat_sub) FROM %I', table_sen) INTO subscription_from;
     execute format('SELECT FROM %I WHERE date_ >= $1', table_sen) using subscription_from;
 END;
$function$
 ;
```

**update**

```
execute format('SELECT FROM %I WHERE date_ >= $1', table_sen) using subscription_from;
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  Why are you trying to select from a table that doesn't exist?

Comment: .@gordon Linoff but my table exist. :D I have table seniority in my schema Client

Comment: The need to do this, might indicate a questionable data model. I would expect a column named `granularity` in a table `seniority` (not different tables with different suffixes)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the schema and the table:

```
table_sen text := 'seniority'||granularity;

execute format('SELECT MIN(dat_sub) FROM %I.%I', 'Client', table_sen) 
  INTO subscription_from;
```

Note that `"Client"` and `client` would be different schema names.

Comment: Now i have this error.  relation "seniority" does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your code results in

```
SELECT MIN(dat_sub) FROM "Client.seniority_day"
```

which treats the whole string as a table name, **not** a table called `seniority_day` in a schema called `client`.

You should do it like this:

```
DECLARE
   table_sen text := 'seniority' || granularity;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT MIN(dat_sub) FROM %I.%I', 'client', table_sen)
      INTO subscription_from;
```

That will result in

```
SELECT MIN(dat_sub) FROM client.seniority_day
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) but got error saying that relation seniority does not exit too. that probably came from my second query .

Comment: i have edited my original post please have a look if you have time .

Comment: Do not change your original question. Now your code doesn't match your text and my answer. Rather, add additional information.

Comment: Sorry im not used with . Shall i rechage as before?

Comment: Yes, please. You can add your modified code at the end.

Comment: Done @Laurenz Albe can you have a look please?

Comment: Of course, you will have to modify your second query in a similar fashion. Did you understand the point of my answer? Your code treats the string `Client.seniority_day` as the name of that table, but in reality the name is `seniority_day`.

Comment: `execute format('SELECT FROM %I.%I WHERE date_ >= $1', 'Client', table_sen) using subscription_from;`

Comment: Do you mean the modification above?